# React-Native AsyncStorage for images

Tags: react-native

My app downloads images from a webserver and saves them, but I am unsure where to save them, is there a local storage for images?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [rn-fetch-blob](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob)

You can

- create file
- delete file
- create directory
- read file
- download file

Comment: For the record:  The above package warns that it is not maintained and points to [wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) instead, which seems to be a maintained (it has regular and recent updates as of now) and useful replacement (without having actually tried it, judging by only the README.md).